# Ejs file not getting rendered when the URL of anchor tag, href is modified

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```
<a class="active" href="/dashboard">
   <i class="fa fa-dashboard">
  </i><span>Dashboard</span>
  </a>

router.get('/dashboard',function(req,res,next){
   res.render('dashboard');
});
```

With this part above, the "dashboard.ejs" file gets rendered as expected but when I modify it as shown below, the "dashboard.ejs" file does not get rendered!

```
 <a class="active" href="/dashboard/dashboardcontent">
   <i class="fa fa-dashboard">
  </i><span>Dashboard</span>
  </a>

router.get('/dashboard/dashboardcontent',function(req,res,next){
   res.render('dashboard');
});
```

and i'm wondering why it is failing to render the file when such small changes are made.

Any help ?

Comment: @Akram , tried it but failed to render !

Comment: @Akram, not really getting what you mean that.

Comment: @Akram, got it solved. Thank U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Before finding the solution:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

As we can see, I had no virtual path prefix created for files that are served by the express.static function !

### The solution:

To create a virtual path prefix (where the path does not actually exist in the file system) for files that are served by the express.static function, specify a mount path for the static directory, as shown below:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I have also added this '/static' to all  CSS, JS, Images links in "layout.ejs" file as shown below:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/static/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--external css-->
<link href="/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/stylesheets/zabuto_calendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/javascripts/gritter/css/jquery.gritter.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/lineicons/style.css">    

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/static/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/stylesheets/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/static/lib/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/dist/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/javascripts/chart-master/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="/static/select2Plugin/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/select2Plugin/select2.min.css" />
```

Source: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

```
       Hope this will be found helpful.
```